# Fotorama gallery and magnifier issue in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2, fotorama

I am using Porto theme in magento 2. I got stuck while using fotorama magnifier and fotorama gallery.

**Magnifier:**
In fotorama magnifier,a I hover the product image, it shows 2 image. Does not zoom properly

**Gallery:**
In gallery, i want 5 images for the first time and then I scroll I will able to see another image of product in product detail(view) page.

fotorama.js

```
 OPTIONS = {
itemdisp: 5,
             nav: 'dots', // 'thumbs' || false
            navposition: 'bottom', // 'top'
            navwidth: null,
            thumbwidth: THUMB_SIZE,
            thumbheight: THUMB_SIZE,
            thumbmargin: MARGIN,
            thumbborderwidth: MARGIN,

            allowfullscreen: false, // true || 'native'

            transition: 'slide', // 'crossfade' || 'dissolve'
            clicktransition: null,
            transitionduration: TRANSITION_DURATION,

            captions: true,

            startindex: 0,

            loop: false,

            autoplay: false,
            stopautoplayontouch: true,

            keyboard: false,

            arrows: true,
            click: true,
            swipe: false,
            trackpad: false,

            shuffle: false,

            direction: 'ltr', // 'rtl'

            shadows: true,

            showcaption: true,

            /**
             * Set type of thumbnail navigation
             */
            navdir: 'horizontal',

            /**
             * Set configuration to show or hide arrows in thumb navigation
             */
            navarrows: true,

            /**
             * Set type of navigation. Can be thumbs or slides
             */
            navtype: 'thumbs'

        },
```

in gallery.phtml

```
"options": {
                "nav": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/nav"); ?>",

                "itemdisp":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/itemdisp"); ?>" /*my custom variable*/
```

in view.xml

```
<var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="itemdisp">5</var><!-- My custom variable -->
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your code.

Comment: i have tried to add new variable for the number of items(images) to be displayed for the first in vertical slider.

Comment: If any other way is there to solve this then please help me

Comment: Please add your code into the original question, to help others answer your question.

Comment: Please help me to solve this..

Comment: Did you solve the issue?